# Where is the class definition for matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib

The class for a matplotlib axes is a `AxesSubplot`:

```
In [233]: type(gca())
Out[233]: matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
```

Yet this name does not appear to exist:

```
In [235]: import matplotlib.axes

In [236]: matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-d2888d8fac12> in <module>()
----> 1 matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AxesSubplot'
2
In [237]: from matplotlib.axes import AxesSubplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-237-86d07b77aa8f> in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.axes import AxesSubplot

ImportError: cannot import name AxesSubplot
```

It's not created using some fancy call of `type()` either; at least, `grep AxesSubplot` does not return any results on the module source file for the `axes` module.

If I look at its mro, I can access the definition for all other classes:

```
In [238]: type(gca()).mro()
Out[238]: 
[matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot,
 matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase,
 matplotlib.axes.Axes,
 matplotlib.artist.Artist,
 builtins.object]
```

How is it possible that `type(gca())` reports `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot`, yet this class appears not to exist there?

I'm on Python 3.2, Matplotlib 1.2, in case it matters.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, I didn't find that question.